# Simple List View in Android crashes if ArrayList is not empty

Tags: android, listview

I have a Problem with a ListView.

Here is my code:

```
private void setViewProtocol() {
        setContentView(R.layout.protocol);
        List<String> logs = new ArrayList<String>();
        logs.add("TEST 1");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.protocol, logs);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It crashes - but when I remove the line logs.add("TEST 1") it works.

Can anyone help me? Why does it work when I call it with an empty list?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your error logs in order to help you to understand your issue.

Comment: are you getting a null pointer exception,post your logcat

Comment: change this :ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, logs);

Comment: If you are passing your own layout then you have to customize it otherwise use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, logs);
```

If you give a custom layout you have to have an TextView with the ID `android.R.id.text1` or you have to override the `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.protocol);

   List<String> logs = new ArrayList<String>();
   logs.add("TEST 1");

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_1, logs);
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.listView1);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: R.layout.simple_list_item_1 should be android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1